# Adjust text size of WebView?

Tags: android

I would like to proportionally decrease the size of all text in a WebView as easily as possible. I've tried `android:textSize="..."` without success. Api Level 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `getSettings().setDefaultFontSize()`, or perhaps `getSettings().setDefaultZoom()`, on your `WebView`.